# Drupal 7 Views Not Seeing CiviCRM fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, fields

I've installed Drupal 7 (7.56) and installed CiviCRM (4.7.27) and the Views Module (with accompanying modules)... however, when I try creating a view... and select "Add a field" the CiviCRM fields are not appearing...

... I have added the variable from sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php e.g. the :

```
$databases['default']['default']['prefix']= array(
'default' => 'drup_',
'civicrm_acl'   => '`adef_civi_`.',
... all the way to...
);
```

after the $databases line:

```
$databases = array('default' => array( 'default' => array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
'database' =>
etc...
```

In the settings.php file, which resides under /sites/default/

Also, the base url is set in the civicrm.settings.php file e.g.

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
     define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 
     'https://www.example.com/');
}
```

Any one have any idea as to why the fields won't show up in Views?

Comment: When you create the View, what Add New View are you doing (Content, User, CiviCRM...)?

Comment: Admin > Structure > Views .. "Add new view" ... Type Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is in my settings.php file, although sanitized to remove actual database names, password, etc (found at the bottom of this post).

After doing that, I make sure that I do a complete cache clear in Drupal so that it picks up the changes I made.

Then I go into Views and choose to make a view that is a CiviCRM type (such as one for events or people) - see screenshot:

[image]

Once I do that and then go to the next page (to create a page, block, etc), then I have the CiviCRM fields available for what I chose. In this example, I selected CiviCRM Events, so the fields are all related to events.

[image]

Here's the code that is in my settings file:

`$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'databasename',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'mypassword',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);`

$databases['default']['default']['prefix']= array(
  'default' => '',
  'civicrm_acl'                              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_acl_cache'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_acl_contact_cache'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_acl_entity_role'                  => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_action_log'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_action_mapping'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_action_schedule'                  => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_activity'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_activity_contact'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_address'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_address_format'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_batch'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_cache'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_campaign'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_campaign_group'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_case'                             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_case_activity'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_case_contact'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_case_type'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_component'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contact'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contact_type'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution_page'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution_product'             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution_recur'               => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution_soft'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_contribution_widget'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_country'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_county'                           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_currency'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_custom_field'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_custom_group'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_dashboard'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_dashboard_contact'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_dedupe_exception'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_dedupe_rule'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_dedupe_rule_group'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_discount'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_domain'                           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_email'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_entity_batch'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_entity_file'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_entity_financial_account'         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_entity_financial_trxn'            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_entity_tag'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_event'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_event_carts'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_events_in_carts'                  => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_extension'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_file'                             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_financial_account'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_financial_item'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_financial_trxn'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_financial_type'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_grant'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_group'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_group_contact'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_group_contact_cache'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_group_nesting'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_group_organization'               => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_im'                               => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_job'                              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_job_log'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_line_item'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_loc_block'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_location_type'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_log'                              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mail_settings'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_abtest'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_bounce_pattern'           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_bounce_type'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_component'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_bounce'             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_confirm'            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_delivered'          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_forward'            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_opened'             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_queue'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_reply'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_subscribe'          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_trackable_url_open' => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_event_unsubscribe'        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_group'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_job'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_recipients'               => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_spool'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mailing_trackable_url'            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_managed'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mapping'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_mapping_field'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership_block'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership_log'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership_payment'               => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership_status'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_membership_type'                  => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_menu'                             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_navigation'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_note'                             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_openid'                           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_option_group'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_option_value'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_participant'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_participant_payment'              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_participant_status_type'          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_payment_processor'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_payment_processor_type'           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_payment_token'                    => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_pcp'                              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_pcp_block'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_persistent'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_phone'                            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_pledge'                           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_pledge_block'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_pledge_payment'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_preferences_date'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_premiums'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_premiums_product'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_prevnext_cache'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_price_field'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_price_field_value'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_price_set'                        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_price_set_entity'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_print_label'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_product'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_queue_item'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_recurring_entity'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_relationship'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_relationship_type'                => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_report_instance'                  => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_saved_search'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_setting'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_sms_provider'                     => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_state_province'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_subscription_history'             => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_survey'                           => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_system_log'                       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_tag'                              => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_tell_friend'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_timezone'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_uf_field'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_uf_group'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_uf_join'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_uf_match'                         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_additional_information_1'   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_commerce_purchases_6'       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_event_information_9'        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_host_location_5'            => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_hotel_information_4'        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_hotels_3'                   => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_member_information_2'       => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_private_training_8'         => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_value_private_trainings_7'        => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_website'                          => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_word_replacement'                 => '`dbname_crm4`.',
  'civicrm_worldregion'                      => '`dbname_crm4`.',
);

Comment: Glad to hear it. Sometimes I've found I just need to see the entire text and process in writing to catch what I've missed. :)